# store documents in descending order(mongodb-insert)

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to add and retrieve documents from collection.I went through mongodb manual and didn't find ways to add documents in descending order by date. Is it possible to add documents to collection in descending order by date while inserting the document as i don't want to query and return the top 50 documents.

TIA.

Comment: [index](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes-introduction/#single-field) the date field in descending order.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB does not guarantee the retrieval order of documents. Even if you insert them in descending order, there is no guarantee the records will be returned in this order.  As suggested by BatScream you could add an descending index on your date field and the order your result when querying the data.